# How to see list of all currently running compute engine instances in GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How do I get a definitive list in the GCP console of all running compute engine instances?

Under 'Deployment Manager', I see many deployments which have a green tick next to them, and give the option to 'STOP' or 'DELETE' - this gives me some concern because those instances should not be running, and they don't appear in the Compute Engine -> VM Instances section of the GCP console.

Note, the `Compute Engine` -> `VM Instances` section of the console looks like this - does this screen confirm that no instances are running?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see all your running instances in the Console of Compute Engine you just have to go to Compute Engine -> VM Instances and use the filter to status:running

[image]

What you are observing in your Console confirm that you have no Compute Engine Instances at all (either stopped or running)